# Image Views not obeying constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I was placing an image view on top of an image, I tried to set the constraints but they didn't seem to have any effect on the position of the image view. 
The constraints I've giving it are :

Align Center X to View
Top Space to Top Layout Guide : 297
width equals 15
height equals 15

Here's a picture of the constraints: [costraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jc6Y.png)

Here's a picture of the simulator running that scene: http://postimg.org/image/9dgpfxawd/

Niall

Comment: Are you saying the checkmark is in the wrong place?  Or the entire checkbox?

Comment: I think you are not insert the height as well as Y postion constarint.

Comment: When dealing with autolayout, should never have any warning (or error). At the bottom right corner of the interface builder you have 4 buttons. Click the fourth and select `All views > update frame`. Then see if your constraints really mean what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the scaling attributes of the image.  Its too big for the area youve defined in constraints, and though the imageview might be the right size, the image itself bleeds over the edge.  If you were to tick the option in IB 'clipSubviews' you might find it chops off your image.  The best solution is really to scale your image to the correct size in an image editing program, if you want to be proper about it.  Then do it again for your different devices.  The easier version is to change the scaling options so the device does it for you - eg 'AspectFit' or 'AspectFill' in IB - you can also set this in code, on the imageview, eg :

```
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: But I've used the same image for loads of image views on that page.

Comment: But the tick is bigger than the box area isnt it.  Maybe you should think about increasing the box size so the tick actually fits - would look neater too.

Comment: No worries, dont forget to pick my answer is chosen one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the checkmark centred over the box, just set the `CenterX` and `CenterY` of the checkmark image to be equal to the `CenterX` and `CenterY` of the box image.

Comment: The field is part of the bigger image(the background). So I can't set it equal to the boxes X and Y.